# How to install driver for S6 Unlocked International

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy, drivers

I have a Samsung Galaxy S6 and I'm trying to use it to test my android application. However, I bought this phone international unlocked so the model type isn't found on the Samsung driver downloads website (http://www.samsung.com/us/support/downloads). How do I get the driver for my phone so that I can use my phone?

Model number: SM-G9208
Baseband version: G9208ZTU2COJ2

Answer (score 0):

I just download [`PdaNet+FoxFi`](http://pdanet.co/a/) and it worked on my ZTE Blade which I couldn't find drivers of it... have a try maybe it solves your problem.